# How to add token to request header in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an API secured by a bearer token. The API has two controllers, one is the default `WeatherForecast` and the second one is for handling CRUD operations for player model. I decided to get my token from `WeatherForecast` and use it to call player in my MVC project.

But when I start debugging, it shows Unauthorized for response in every MVC action. It's ok on using postman though.

Here are the controller methods for `HttpGet` and `HttpPost`:

```
namespace MyMVCProject.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;
        
        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _clientFactory = clientFactory;
        }
        
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost:42045/weatherforecast/");
            var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                string token = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("JwtToken", token);
            }
        
            return View();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllPlayers()
        {
            var accessToken = HttpContext.Session.GetString("JwtToken");
            List<Player> players = new List<Player>();
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost:42045/api/player");

            var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();

            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var apiString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                players = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Player>>(apiString);
            }

            return View(players);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddPlayer(Player player)
        {
            var accessToken = HttpContext.Session.GetString("JwtToken");
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost:42045/api/player/");

            if (player != null)
            {
                request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(player), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created)
            {
                var apiString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                player = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Player>(apiString);
                TempData["success"] = "Player Added Successfully!";
            }
            else if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            {
                TempData["badrequest"] = "Player with the same name already exists";
            }

            return View(player);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the token correctly? Perhaps you are not parsing the JWT correctly and consequently not passing the correct Bearer token.

Comment: using breakpoint, the value of accessToken is the same as the token saved by session previously in Index action. value of headers in request.Headers.Authorization is correct (Authorization: Bearer+ token, but without space between them) and after that the response value is UnAuthorized!

Answer (score 2):

`HttpRequestMessage` has a Headers property of type `HttpRequestHeaders`. This class has two `Add` methods you can use.

You can add headers like this:

```
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + YourToken);
```

Comment: I used your sample code, But after I ran a debugger, It showed me Bearer+ token value without any space! It must be something like Bearer token, Right? I used string.PadRight but It's still the same! I was wondering if this is the real problem for the action to reach the API

Comment: That may be because you are not passing the string correctly

Comment: What do you mean by that? I'm sure that there's something wrong with MVC-side actions, Because it works well using Postman on API as I said. What's your suggestion?

Comment: Pass Bearer with a space. That's why there is no space

Answer (score 0):

I am using this syntax

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
```